# d3 x-axis has issue when there are duplicate values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I am having issues with d3 with duplicate x-values. Here is a plunkr that shows this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6OFiMJFWsRDx5nMel6lY?p=preview

The only thing that is probably relevant to this issue is

```
     x.domain(option.labels);
```

As you can see the labels that are supposed to show up are

```
["Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
```

But what ends up on the screen

```
["Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu"]
```

It appears to have skipped the duplicate here. I tried playing with the tickValues option but cannot get it to work right.

This issue holds even if the labels look like

```
["Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Sun", "Thu"] - //Sun repeating in the middle also is taken out
```

Any help with getting all of the labels (including repetitions) is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Set your x axis up as a time scale instead of an ordinal scale. Use real dates (or timestamps) as the data points for this axis and then use the d3 time formatting stuff to display it however you need ("Fri."). Seems like a bunch of extra work but it will save you a bunch of time in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Each unique value has only 1 point on x axis. If you have 2 different Mondays - they have different date. So x axis should be date, and tick label should be formatted to show only day of a week.

Comment: Sorry but that is not an option for me; data arrives in that format. I changed the strategy to use a numeric domain and wrote a tickFormat to format the x tick values. Thanks for your help.